# Any way to find out the which objects use or populate a particular table in oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design, sql-execution-plan, database-metadata

I have a certain requirement where in I have been given a table name say ABC, i want to find out which all procedures,packages,mv's,functions refer to that particular table 'ABC' or do a insert or update on that table. Is there any way or query to find this.

Since I cannot look up the code of every object in the schema, I am searching for another way.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tables_referenced_inside_pl_sql_procedures.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may use Oracle System view `dba_dependencies` (check with your dba if you don't have access to this view).

```
select * 
  from dba_dependencies 
 where referenced_name='ABC' 
   and referenced_type='TABLE';
```

Beware, your objects may also use synonyms. So a second list could come with:

```
select * 
  from dba_dependencies 
 where referenced_name='ABC' 
   and referenced_type='SYNONYM';
```

Comment: Thanks...will ask my dba to run and check, I guess i don't have access.